# How do i get my web view fit to screen?

Tags: android, video, layout, webview, flv

I have implemented a web view to play a embedded flv video in my application. And it WORKS! but the problem is video frame is too small.. (video only takes about 1/8 of the screen) How can i make my video fit to screen?

Here's my code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webvideo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;  
private LinearLayout mContentView;
private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.fortunagate.com/adaderana_apps/video_player.php?video=http://derana.lk/content/video/SriGauthamaSambuddha24-15thJune2014.flv");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            private View mCustomView;

             @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
            {
                // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
                if (mCustomView != null)
                {
                    callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                    return;
                }

                // Add the custom view to its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER);
                mCustomView = view;
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;

                // hide main browser view
                mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Finally show the custom view container.
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCustomViewContainer.bringToFront();
            }

        }); 

      webview.loadUrl(url);

      return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

} 
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#FF000000"/>

<LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

     <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have your WebView like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#FF000000"/>

   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, when you want it to appear just change the `visibility` to `visible` and it will cover the entire screen.

Comment: what do you mean by 'when you want' . Shouldn't i just set the visibility to visible and use?

Comment: Do you want the Webview in this case to cover the entire screen right away? If you do, why do you have a FrameLayout in the same layout file?

Comment: Eventhough i removed FrameworkLayout the video plays on a small player.